# html form radio buttons not saving string to database

Tags: php, html, database, localhost

I have a html form which includes a question involving three radio buttons. I want the word 'road', 'both' or gravel' to be saved to my database. This field is set up as a varchar in the database.

This is my html:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Do you prefer just road or gravel/trail cycling as well?</label>

        <label for="road">Just road</label>
        <input type="radio" name="bike_terrain" id="road" value="road" required/>
        <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $bike_terrain_err; ?></span>

        <label for="both">Both</label>
        <input type="radio" name="bike_terrain" id="both" value="both" />
        <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $bike_terrain_err; ?></span>                

        <label for="gravel">Just gravel/trail</label>
        <input type="radio" name="bike_terrain" id="gravel" value="gravel" />
        <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $bike_terrain_err; ?></span>

    </div>
```

I am then using php to validate the input is not empty:

```
    if(empty($_POST["bike_terrain"])){
        $bike_terrain_err = "Please select a bike terrain.";
    } else {
        $bike_terrain = isset($_POST["bike_terrain"]);
    }
```

And php to send it to my localhost database:

```
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($email_err) && empty($bike_terrain_err)) {
        
        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, terrain) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
         
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $param_username, $param_email, $param_terrain);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            $param_email = $email;
            $param_terrain = $bike_terrain;
            

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Redirect to login page
                header("location: login.php");
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.248";
            }
        }
    }
```

(Note: I have cut out some of the other fields that I am inserting for simplicity)

$bike_terrain has previously been initialised as a string.

The problem is that nothing is being saved to the terrain field in my database and I don't know why!

Thank you very much! All suggestions, thoughts or ideas are very welcome.

Comment: Why do you set $bike_terrain = isset($_POST["bike_terrain"])? This will lead to a boolean value instead of the string you want

Comment: Oh I see my mistake now! I didn't understand how the isset() function works but I have changed it to use that in an if statement then post the value without it. Thank you very much @user1915746 .

Answer (score -1):

Something like this (untested) should do the trick. you save the same radio with the same name so it would look like a selection somehow.

Had to quickly code from my mobile device XD

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$host = '127.0.0.1';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'people_db'

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die ('Cannot connect'.mysqli_error());
$fullname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['fullname']);
$gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['gender']);

$q = "insert into employeedb (fullname, gender) values ('".$fullname."', '".$gender."')";
mysqli_result($con,$q);
echo 'Data Saved to Database!';

}

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Save Radio to DB</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="people" method="POST" action="index.php"
    <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Enter your name"/><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"/>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```